# Strange shadowing of non-virtual function by virtual function in gcc 4.7.2

Tags: c++, inheritance, gcc

I wonder if it's a very strange (for me) language feature or a compiler bug:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class A{
public:

  virtual void func(T const & x)
  { std::cout << "A func: " << x << "\n"; }

  void func(T const &x, T const & y)
  { std::cout << "Double func:\n";
    func(x); func(y);
  }
};

template<class T>
class B : public A<T>{
public:

  virtual void func(T const & x)
  { std::cout << "B func: " << x << "\n";  }
};

int main(){
  A<int> a;
  a.func(1);
  a.func(2,3);
  B<int> b;
  b.func(1);
  b.func(2,3);
}
```

Both a.func(1) and a.func(2,3) work perfectly OK. But b.func(2,3) produces:

```
3.c++: In function ‘int main()’:
3.c++:27:13: error: no matching function for call to ‘B<int>::func(int, int)’
3.c++:27:13: note: candidate is:
3.c++:20:16: note: void B<T>::func(const T&) [with T = int]
3.c++:20:16: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not called shadowing, but **hiding**, and yes, it's a language feature.

You can make the base function available with a `using` directive:

```
template<class T>
class B : public A<T>{
public:
    using  A<T>::func;  // <----------------
    virtual void func(T const & x)
      { std::cout << "B func: " << x << "\n";  }
};
```